# handling persistence exceptions

Tags: java, sql, database, exception, jakarta-ee

I got a minor problem with catching exceptions. I've got code like this:

```
Role r=new Role("default");
r.setId(Role.DEFAULT_ID);
u.getRoles().add(r); // u is instance of entity which is in relation manytomany with r
try{
   em.persist(u);
}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e.getClass().getName()+" - default role not found, creating...");
   em.persist(r);
   em.persist(u);
}
```

Hope the point of this is clear. If the default role does not yet exist an exception is supposed to be catched, the role is created and then it's given another shot. However I can't catch any exception.

The error log of first two exceptions thrown is:

```
[org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-5) could not insert collection: [Comic.model.User.roles#5] [insert into USER_ACCOUNT_ROLE (USER_ACCOUNT_uid, roles_rid) values (?, ?)]
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ...blabla you dont follow constraints
```

.

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert collection: [Comic.model.User.roles#5]
```

I guess I can't catch any exception since it's thrown outside my try block right? Any suggestions what could I do about this?

Comment: Your `catch(Exception e)` will make it hard for you to figure out what's going on. You should catch the specific exception you're looking for, or it will be very confusing when a different one is thrown.

Comment: Is there any chance the second or third line could throw an exception? If so you may need to nest Try/Catch blocks.

Comment: @artbristol: i agree with you, but for the moment i need first to catch something.

Comment: In my limited experience, once the JPA/Hibernate-layer has thrown an exception, the session/transaction you're working in is invalidated and you can't retry stuff that hits the JPA-layer, like a new save or something. This is not likely to be the case always, but what you attempt to do would be impossible in the environment I work in. My solution would be to query/check if what I want to catch with an exception will be true/false instead of relying on catching an exception for logic control.

Comment: @JustinC: no i don't think these lines could possibly throw exception, but ok, just to make sure i'm gonna try it out.

Comment: @Martin Peters: yea... that's what i didnt want to do, but it seems i got no other choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your User entity  I think your relationship to Role can/should be ManyToMany.

You should not need to manually be managing persisting the object graph, as you are doing in the catch block, if you place a [CascadeType.PERSIST](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html) on that relationship as well.

Answer (score 1):

If em.persist() throws and Exception.  Then it seems strange that you would call the method again (twice) in your catch statement.

Either you need to add another try catch, inside your catch statement to deal with a second exception.

Or you need to change your logic to check for the need to persist the role first rather than handling it with Exception catching.

Comment: i would give you the right answer too since your advice helped as well but there can be just one right answer and terrell was a little bit closer :)